# How long is my too-long question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, area-51, character-limit

In Area 51, you can't submit example questions longer than 150 characters; ok, that's fine (although I think the limit should be larger).

But a character counter would be very helpful there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch! We added a character counter.

Comment: You seem to have a ♦, but I don't recall your name. Are you one of the NYC team?

Comment: Yup- started a few months ago, and decided it's finally time to start trolling meta :)

Comment: Did you start after the question you asked? Because I remember the question, just not the diamond.